# My wireless adapter is seen in terminal but I cannot connect to wifi in VirtualBox Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, kali-linux, wireless-bridge

I have a problem where my VirtualBox does not scan wifi through my wireless adapter but is connected to the ethernet of host machine.

When I do ifconfig then my wireless adapter is shown.

```
   ifconfig      
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.6  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe53:8351  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:53:83:51  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1  bytes 590 (590.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 32  bytes 4954 (4.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 4  bytes 240 (240.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4  bytes 240 (240.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        unspec 66-D7-7B-01-03-75-00-D6-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 2101  bytes 236482 (230.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 2101  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Also if I take my adapter to monitor mode then it has no problem:

```
wconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  Mode:Monitor  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

But my wireless adapter is not shown in my wifi section.

[image]

Comment: What is the guest OS? What is the host OS? [Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: (1) For every fact, command, output, snippet or screenshot you should clearly state if it's from the host or from the guest. (2) There is no question in your "question", the post is just a set of statements. What is your question? // Please [edit] and improve.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand of your question, you are trying the Host wireless adapter directly in the Guest machine. This does not work.

The Guest machine will always use the Host Ethernet adapter unless connected as per below by a card enabled by USB pass through.

If you wish wireless in the Guest, get a USB Wireless Card (I use Panda) and then use USB Pass Through to connect USB wireless in the Guest machine.